# How to use output of one jdbc request to insert data for another jdbc query

Tags: jmeter

I am using first JDBC request to fetch values of one column from my oracle DB. I am storing it an output variable 'DCN'. Now I need to insert all the data extracted from this query into my second JDBC request. I am wondering if there is a way to insert the data in one single query rather than using for each controller to loop over each of the value present in the variable 'DCN'.
Following is the query I ma using in the second JDBC request and it's child of ForEach Controller

```
INSERT INTO Data (FILENET_DCN)
VALUES ('${DCN}');
Select @@rowcount;
```

If i try to use this query outside of ForEach controller, then instead of values, "${DCN}" (literal text) is what gets inserted into the table as it is.

For Each Controller:

[ForEach controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIYX4.png)

Comment: It should work. Did you check with debug sampler it has the value for DCN?

Comment: yes, I did check debug sampler too and I could see data stored in DCN as:

JMeterVariables:
DATE1=02-Jul-2018
DATE2=01-Feb-2017
DATE3=01-Mar-2016
DATE4=01-Apr-2017
DCN_#=5
DCN_1=a1
DCN_2=a2
DCN_3=a3
DCN_4=a4
DCN_5=a5
DCN_id=a5

Another observation: If i use DCN as result variable, I could see values getting inserted in the query. but it fails to do so if I am putting DCN as Variable Name

Comment: Show ForEach Controller

Comment: Image added to the question itself

Answer (score 0):

Use ForEach's output variable `DCN_id`

```
  VALUES ('${DCN_id}');
```

Comment: That's what I am already using, but I am trying to figure out a more efficient way to do it.

Comment: @vsingh in this questio your issue is *${DCN}" (literal text) is what gets*

Comment: Right, I start getting literal text if I try using. Following code (JDBC request) without for each loop. Insert query within for each is adding more time because it goes over each of the value from FCN separately. So I wanted to try using one insert with all the values in one go and that might dave time
    INSERT INTO Data (FILENET_DCN)
    VALUES ('${DCN}');